# Login repeats after authenticate, if i try to send a friends request

Tags: facebook, post, authentication, invite

Im trying to build a 'cheer action' for my app. It is a game in iPhone, so I want to post a 'welcome message' in the users wall (I will need 'public_stream' permission) and then invite his friends to visit my webpage.

Here my question.. I authenticate the user using:

```
_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=" + app_id + "&redirect_uri=" + app_net_folder + auth_response_uri + "&state=" + session_id;
```

I get response in my uri, and then I get the access_token, user_id, etc. 
Then I post a message in his wall in this way:

```
_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" + app_id;
_url += "&message=" + string_ToUrl(String_ToHTML(request_msg));
```

Now I want to invite his friends (using a multi friend list dialog). To do it, I can only use JavaScript FB.ui. In this way:

```
FB.init({appId  : app_id,   logging : false, frictionlessRequests: true, oauth : true});

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: msg, title: title}, requestCallback);
```

When I do it, a window is opened asking me again for the user's login.. but my user has been already authenthicated. So I dont know how to say to FB in JavaScript that my user has been alredy authenthicated! (I even have the access_token, but I don't know how to use it in JavaScript functions).

Someone knows what am I doing wrong? or how to do those two actions asking just one time for the user's login?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are already log in, you can get login user id using below code

```
var userId = FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().uid;
if(userId > 0 || userId != '')
{
  alert('user is already log in');
}
```

hope it's helpful to you

Comment: Thanks. but it doesn't avoid that Fb.ui ask me for login again :( FB.getLoginStatus returns that user is logged in, and I get everything about him (user id, access token, etc). But when I use FB.ui (just after FB.getLoginStatus returns 'user is logged'), it always ask me for login again...

Comment: try this way, try to code fb.ui related code in else part
if(userId > 0 || userId != '')
{
  alert('user is already log in');
}else{ // FB.ui  part}